# history.js + Google

Tags: javascript, ajax, history.js, hashbang

Let's talk about AJAX-crawling by google:

Since [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) is a nice alternative to ugly [hashbang](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification) urls I was wondering about one certain issue: 
For HTML5 browsers, nice urls are created if ajax-content is loaded and should be indexed by google. For none-HTML5 browsers (e.g. IE 9 does not support history.pushState) the old hashbang is used.

So which version is seen by google? Are there any risks google sees duplicate content (one time with nice url, one time with hashbang) ?

Thank you for any thoughts on that.

Answer (score 0):

If a ajax page needs to be indexed with google we need to server a html snapshot of the page from the server.

For ex: xyz.com/page1#!name=john

Google crawler finds this #! identifier and requests http://xyz.com/page1?_escaped_fragment_=name=john
This way our server can server the html snapshot of the page.

Now when our URLs are prettified and appended with #! ajax pages will be indexed.

For pages with only # appended in the URLs, google crawler won;t be able to see the content loaded via ajax and it won't be indexed. So there won't be any possibility of duplication

We can also use the link tag in the head section of the page with rel cannonical url pointing to the mail url. See http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html for reference.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<a href="http://some/other/page/1" data-history='{"some":"data"}' title="...">link1</a>
<a href="http://some/other/page/2" data-history='{"some":"data"}' title="...">link2</a>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-history]', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    History.pushState($(this).data().history, this.title, this.href);
})
```

For client with JavaScript enabled, the hisotory.js will handle this to an AJAX request, for client without JavaScript, it will request the normal page.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use solely HTML5 History API for browsers that support the API (about 70% of browsers) while serving regular static pages to browsers that do not. This way, there will be no possibility that search engines will see anything different from full canonical static URLs.